# Should I need to create mock object by passing mock values and pass that to thenReturn or can i just pass new Class() in Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

Which is the better way to write junit?

```java
className object = new className("test");
when(className.someMethod()).thenReturn(object);
```

OR

```java
when(className.someMethod()).thenReturn(new className());
```

Comment: Please follow the standard naming conventions (e.g. class names start with a capital case character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine and depend on your use case. With the first approach you still have direct access to the return value.

If you don't need it (e.g. in your assert statement), then the second approach is fine as well.

Simple Java rules. Nothing special.